# Convert multiple columns into rows based on identity column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data something like below:

| CANDIDATE_ID | jid 1 | type1 | score1 | jid 2 | type2 | score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | A | 100 | 3 | C | 300 |
| 13 | 2 | B | 200 | 4 | D | 400 |

I want to convert this dataframe in something like this

| CANDIDATE_ID | jid | type1 | score1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | A | 100 |
| 12 | 3 | C | 300 |
| 13 | 2 | B | 200 |
| 13 | 4 | D | 400 |

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the dataframes built from the two sets of columns (renaming the xxx2 ones):

```
df_out = pd.concat([df[['CANDIDATE_ID', 'jid 1', 'type1', 'score1']],
                    df[['CANDIDATE_ID', 'jid 2', 'type2', 'score2']].rename(
                        columns= {'jid 2': 'jid 1', 'type2': 'type1', 'score2': 'score1'}
                    )]).sort_values('CANDIDATE_ID').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   CANDIDATE_ID  jid 1 type1  score1
0            12      1     A     100
1            12      3     C     300
2            13      2     B     200
3            13      4     D     400
```